# Some difficulties with VB.net code

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm a beginner in WinForms VB NET programming. I need to create text box at a run time.

I found example in a search engine how to implement this:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim TextControl As TextBox
    ControlID = ControlID + 1
    Load Text1(ControlID)
    Set TextControl = Text1(ControlID)
    With TextControl
        .Left = (Text1(ControlID - 1).Left + Text1(ControlID - 1).Width) + 10
        .Top = 20
        .Width = 100
        .Height = 20
        .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub
```

But I have some difficulties with example's code.

Would someone explain the following VB NET code rows?

```
    Load Text1(ControlID)
    Set TextControl = Text1(ControlID)
    With TextControl
    End With
```

Comment: Um. Where did you get that from? So far as I'm aware, `Load` was VB6 (and earlier), and doesn't exist in VB.NET. (The presence of `Set` is another clue that this might not by VB.NET code)

Comment: this is not vb.net code - it is old visual basic code (I think VB 6). Although it looks the same, vb.net is not backwards compatible to VB 6. You want an example in VB 6 or in VB.net?

Comment: Ando,thank you i need example in VB NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the following example that does exactly what you want to:

```
Private Sub btnCreateTextbox_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreateTextbox.Click
    Dim textbox1 As New TextBox
    textbox1.Name = "Textbox1"
    textbox1.Size = New Size(170, 20)
    textbox1.Location = New Point(167, 32)
    GroupBox1.Controls.Add(textbox1)
End Sub
```

look for reference and good explanation: http://www.authorcode.com/create-dynamic-textbox-and-label-in-vb-net/

Answer (score 1):

It's VB code.

"Load Text1(ControlID)"
It means load Text1(controlID) into memory , Text1(controlID) is a textbox control.

Answer (score 1):

Add a textbox at desired location at desig time same code genrated in designer file. Copy the code and paste under Command1_Click().